# Shortening my if statement

Tags: java

I am trying to have people put in their assignments and get a graded based on those numbers. I need an if statement to tell them their grade. This is what i have so far. It all works I just need the if statement shortened. This is what I have:

```
if (pC >= 93 ) 
        {
            System.out.print("\n Your grade is an A");
        }
        else if (pC >= 90) 
        {
            System.out.print("\n Your grade is a A-");
        }
        else if (pC >= 87)
        {
            System.out.print("\n Your grade is a B+");
        }
        else if (pC >= 83)
        {
            System.out.print("\n Your grade is a B");
        }
        else if (pC >= 80)
        {
            System.out.print("\n Your grade is a B-");
        }
        else if (pC >= 77)
        {
            System.out.print("\n Your grade is a C+");
        }
        else if (pC >= 73)
        {
            System.out.print("\n Your grade is a C");
        }
        else if (pC >= 70)
        {
            System.out.print("\n Your grade is a C-");
        }
        else if (pC >= 67)
        {
            System.out.print("\n Your grade is a D+");
        }
        else if (pC >= 63)
        {   
            System.out.print("\n Your grade is a D");
        }
        else if (pC >= 60)
        {
            System.out.print("\n Your grade is a D-");
        }
        else if (pC <= 59)
        {
            System.out.print("\n Your grade is a F");
        }
```

Comment: Heard about the Switch, eh ?

Comment: Sometimes a bunch of if statements really is just the simplest way. A switch will be basically the same length and complexity

Comment: Why does it need to be shorter?

Comment: Use a data table instead and binsearch it. By the way, if fractional values are allowed then you're missing the 59. something values. It will be easier to configure the grade bands of you do that.

Comment: You can use switch case as a alternative but there is no other shorter way for doing the same.

Comment: Shorter in terms of... Fewer characters? Easy: don't repeat `System.out.print("\n Your grade is a ` on each line.

Comment: I don't think a switch statement simplifies things here. I would stick with your existing code.

Answer (score 8):

You can build a table of threshold and grade label.

```
final int [] lbound =   {93, 90, 87, 83, 80, 77, 73, 70, 67, 63, 60, Integer.MIN_VALUE};
final String [] label = {"n A", " A-", " B+", " B", " B-", " C+", " C", " C-", " D+", " D", " D-", " F"};

for (int i = 0; i < lbound.length; ++i) {
    if (pC >= lbound[i]) {
        System.out.print("\n Your grade is a" + label[i]);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nit: this doesn't quite do the same... Thanks, irregular English indefinite pronouns!

Comment: +1 :) one more thing you can do. replace pC <= 59 with pC < 60 or add 1 in all lbound and pC > lbound[i]

Comment: You have traded a few lines of simple if statements for a bunch of complexity. In the long run the more verbose code will be simpler for other coders to understand and maintain. I think this refactor doesn't help.

Comment: @AndyTurner Thanks for your reminder. Fixed "an" vs "a".

Comment: I am not a fan of the separate arrays as the indexes could be messed up easily. If I was going to do an approach like this, I would create a Dictionary.

Answer (score 3):

Your code contains a lot of redundancy which is easy to eliminate. The essence of the logic is a mapping from test score to grade, so you need an expression or a function which does *just that* and nothing else, and then the rest of the code does the printing in a uniform way. If you are happy with hardcoded values, a properly formatted conditional expression is the cleanest:

```
String grade = 
      pC >= 93 ? "A"
    : pC >= 90 ? "A-"
    : pC >= 87 ? "B+"
    : pC >= 83 ? "B"
    : pC >= 80 ? "B-"
    : pC >= 77 ? "C+"
    : pC >= 73 ? "C"
    : pC >= 70 ? "C-"
    : pC >= 67 ? "D+"
    : pC >= 63 ? "D"
    : pC >= 60 ? "D-"
    : "F";    
System.out.println("\n Your grade is a "+grade);
```

Comment: This is by FAR the most elegant solution. There are no additional objects or loops created, and it is very compact.

Answer (score 2):

I see a pattern in your grading system, which can be used to build a data structure:

- Ten's place digit decide the grade - `A` (more than 90), or `B` (more than 80, but less than 90), so on...
- One's place digit decide the subGrade - `+` (7 or more), `-` (0 to 3), or plain grade (3 to 5).

You can build 2 maps storing those mappings:

```
// These two maps can be moved to a common better place
TreeMap<Integer, String> gradeMapRules = new TreeMap<Integer, String>();
gradeMapRules.put(9, "A");
gradeMapRules.put(8, "B");
gradeMapRules.put(7, "C");
gradeMapRules.put(6, "D");
gradeMapRules.put(0, "F");

TreeMap<Integer, String> subGradeMapRules = new TreeMap<Integer, String>();
subGradeMapRules.put(0, "-");
subGradeMapRules.put(3, "");
subGradeMapRules.put(7, "+");
```

Then given a marks, you can get it's grade like this:

```
int pC = 75;
String grade = gradeMapRules.floorEntry(pC / 10).getValue();
String subGrade = !"F".equals(grade) ? subGradeMapRules.floorEntry(pC % 10).getValue() : "";
String finalGrade = grade + subGrade;
```

Comment: If choosing maps, then a `TreeMap` is superior, with its `NavigableMap` API. I think `floorEntry` applies here.

Comment: But with your elegant math analysis, I would even prefer those few data points hardcoded in a conditional expression.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Hmm, if this is to be used in a single place, then I would too prefer your solution :)